# Is there any possibility to overlay images in canvas?

Tags: html, canvas

So that is, is there any possibility to overlay images in canvas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please be a **lot** more detailed next time. I assume you mean overlay images with some sort of transparency.

---

Yes. All you need to do is call `drawImage` with the several images in the order you want them to appear.

Before you draw any given image you can change its opacity by setting `ctx.globalAlpha` to a number between 0 and 1. Make sure you set it back afterward the `drawImage` call that you wanted it to affect, so the next image gets drawn as intended.

Comment: Oh thanks, that was what I meant, sorry for my lack of info, I'll do my best next time.